# Skip before filter according to custom logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, before-filter

Is there a way to skip a before filter on a Rails4 app controller according to some custom logic?

Something like

`ruby
before_filter :do_it, unless: { params['name'] == 'IWannaSkipThis' }`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do it.

```
before_filter { |c| c.check_param params['name'] }

def check_param(param_name)
  #perform checking here
  "do what you want" unless param_name == 'IWannaSkipThis'
end
```

But, whenever you perform an action on this controller, it will expect `params['name']`

Update: If you are using Rails 4.0, then it should be `before_action` rather than `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I'm actually doing now but I don't like how it looks like.